# Fallo En El Login Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, sql-server

este es mi codigo, pero a la hora de realizar el Login que esta conectado con Sql Server , no funciona, falla el While (rs.next()).  No es leido por el programa, debo solucionarlo lo antes posible,dejo mi codigo para que porfavor me ayuden a solucionar esto. gracias.

```
public boolean logear() {
        try {
        //Se obtiene la conexión
        Connection connect = conexionBD();
        //Se genera la consulta

        Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select EMAIL,PASSW from REGISTRO where EMAIL='" + edemail.toString() + "' and PASSW='" + edpassword.toString() + "'");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Primera Parte",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      //   datosConsultado =rs.getString("EMAIL,PASSW");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Segunda Parte", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        while (rs.next()) {

            datosConsultado =rs.getString("EMAIL,PASSW");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tECERA Parte", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


        if(datosConsultado!=null){

            Intent intent = new Intent(principio.this, pagina.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bienvenido Amigo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario No Existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //Se cierra la conexión
        connect.close();
        //Mostramos los datos obtenidos
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Se acabo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //Mostramos el error en caso de no conectarse
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Muestra que es lo que te esta dando el logCat

Comment: Cuando se hace el Debuggeo, salta el While y no realiza la validacion de datos desde Sql server

Comment: @DavidDominguez no entra porque el RS no contiene datos, para obtener el valor dentro de un  EditText usa el metodo getText() y toString() para obtener su valor tipo String.

Answer (score 0):

Salta el `while` porque no tiene valores el `Recordset`, en realidad tu Query esta formándose incorrectamente, si estas usando `EditText` y deseas obtener los valores del texto escrito en estas vistas, debes realizarlo usando los métodos:

```
getText().toString();
```

Por lo tanto aplica esto a tu Query

```
 ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select EMAIL,PASSW from REGISTRO where EMAIL='" + edemail.getText().toString() + "' and PASSW='" + edpassword.getText().toString() + "'");
```

---

Puedes agregar esta validación, en caso de no existir resultados no realiza el `while` :

```
if(!rs.next()){

    Log.i("Database","No se encontraron datos.");

   return false;

}else{

  while(rs.next()){
    //*Obtiene resultados.
  }

}
```

Comment: Seguimos presentando el fallo, el codigo al debugearse, evita el While y avanza al If. Por lo tanto el error se presenta  a la hora de ejecutar el Rs.Next

Comment: @DavidDominguez el RS seguramente no tiene resultados agrega la validación que comento en mi respuesta. ¿ Puedes revisar directamente el query por ejemplo en el SQL server MS?

Comment: la base de datos de Sql Server esta funcionando bien, incluso realiza las consultas y todo. No esta realizando la entrada ni identifica el rs.next(), es algo molesto jajja

Comment: @DavidDominguez rs es null o simplemente no llama a next(), si no llama a este método significa que el query no obtuvo datos.

Comment: el rs tiene el siguiente codigo.
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select EMAIL,PASSW from REGISTRO where EMAIL='" + edemail.getText().toString() + "' and PASSW='" + edpassword.getText().toString() + "'");
           
La conexion a la base de datos se realiza antes y queda establecido todo, pero sigue presentando el fallo

Comment: agregaste la validación que comento? if(!rs.next()){

    Log.i("Database","No se encontraron datos.");

   return false;

} que realiza? imprime algo el LogCat?

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus respectivas ayudas, ya despues de tomarme el tiempo de leer el codigo, pude validar este tema como tal.

Comment: y como lo validaste @DavidDominguez ?

Comment: Quieren que adjunte el codigo corregido?

Comment: @DavidDominguez solo somos una sola persona, si esta pregunta no te ayudo a solucionar tu problema, agrega una respuesta con la solución explicando que sucedio.

Comment: gracias por tu comentario, pronto adjuntare codigos de respuesta a problemas cotidianos que se presentan a la hora del desarrollo. El registro que se necesita es un Login, el cual se declara de dos maneras pero reduciendo codigo.